# No routes found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I recently upgrade to Rails 3, and after fixing most of the issues I have my server running.  However, I amgetting a rather usual error:

```
Started GET "/" for 10.0.0.1 at Sat May 14 00:37:26 +0000 2011                                                                                                                                                                         

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/"):
```

when I try to visit http://localhost:9292/

for reference I'm running my server via `rackup`.

If I look in my routes.rb file, I see:

```
RailsRoot::Application.routes do 
    # ...
    match '/', :to => "application#show"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    root :to => 'application#show' 
    # ...
end
```

For reference `application` is a controller and it does have an action `show`, and my application is named `RailsRoot`.

Given that I believe I've constructed my routes correctly it seems likely that I've installed something wrong or something went wrong in the upgrade, but I'm not sure where seeing as almost everything else is working.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: What does `rake routes` display?

Comment: @Jon `Don't know how to build task 'routes'`

Comment: Can you post your `config/application.rb` and `config/environment.rb` files?

Comment: @dmark [application](http://pastie.org/1898919) and [environment](http://pastie.org/1898926)

Comment: @tzenes something is very wrong if `rake routes` says that. What version of rails are you using? For 3.0.7 the first line of your routes file should say `RailsRoot::Application.routes.draw do`. Notice the ".draw". But I think there is a bigger problem. How exactly did you go about upgrading?

Comment: @Jonathan turns out I was just missing the `.draw`.  If you'd be kind enough to supply that as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb, change this line

```
RailsRoot::Application.routes do
```

to this

```
RailsRoot::Application.routes.draw do
```